# jquery won't show basic auth popup

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

I load a list of xml files with $.ajax.

Some of these are protected by Basic Auth, under the xml path there is an htaccess.

Not all are protected.

How i can load protected and not protected file?
If i set the header or the beforeSend with btoa(user & pass) i can load only the protected, but the not protectd give me error.

If i not set header or beforesend for the autehtication, i want to show the browser popup for login, but it not show and give me this error and return error.status 0:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/path/file.xml?no=1381827329. Origin http://www.domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The header of the request :

```
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://www.domain.com
Referer:http://www.domain.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36
```

I think the problem is that are not in list

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Thank's to all and sorry for my bad english, Bye!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the Same-origin policy. See:

- WIki:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy
- Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FSame_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

why this is happening.

Use JSONP or HTTP access control (CORS) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS ) to avoid this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

The problem is only when i set the htaccess with the basic auth, if i remove the basic auth from the htaccess there is no problem with CORS.